# One norm inequality

Tags: real-analysis

how can be the following inequality proved:$$\|x-y\|\|z\| \le\|x-z\|\|y\|+\|y-z\|\|x\|$$
($x,y,z$ are vectors from $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|\cdot\|$ is the euclidean norm).

Thanks in advance.